# Strawberry Perl 5.12 as PostgreSQL 9.0's plperl on win32?

Tags: perl, postgresql, strawberry-perl, plperl, perl5.12

Has anyone had luck with this combination?

So far I've gotten the message:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0/lib/plperl.dll":
The specified module could not be found.
```

...to go away by making a copy of perl512.dll and renaming it perl510.dll.  Now I'm having issues installing some modules I need, so I can't tell if it's not working because of that, or because the PostgreSQL binary I have is designed for Perl 5.10, because the error message is now:

```
WARNING:  Use of uninitialized value $prolog in concatenation (.) or string at -e line 25.
CONTEXT:  compilation of PL/Perl function "my_function"
WARNING:  Use of uninitialized value $src in concatenation (.) or string at -e line 25.
CONTEXT:  compilation of PL/Perl function "my_function"


ERROR:  didn't get a CODE reference from compiling function "my_function"
CONTEXT:  compilation of PL/Perl function "my_function"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would need a recompile.  I tried removing the module dependency from my function, just making it a simple return statement, and it still had the same error.

That, or Strawberry Perl 5.10 instead of 5.12.

Comment: From the [pginstaller page](http://pginstaller.projects.postgresql.org/) (26.11.11): "PL/perl requires ActiveState Perl 5.8 to be installed (5.10 for PostgreSQL 8.4 and above)." - Good to know it appears to also work with Strawberry.